# iOS Charts - place Y value label at the bottom instead of the top of the circle

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I guess the title says it all. The Charts lib is really awesome but quite big at the same time and I'm having troubles finding the right setup.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of what I have. I'd like to place the red (negative) entry label at the bottom of the circle so it doesn't interfere with the green line.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you are using a LineChart. To change the yValue of the label you'll have to override the `drawValues` function in a subclass of [`LineChartRenderer.swift`](https://github.com/PhilJay/ios-charts/blob/master/Charts/Classes/Renderers/LineChartRenderer.swift)

Specifically you'll have to modify the y value here:

```
ChartUtils.drawText(context: context,
                    text: formatter.stringFromNumber(e.value)!,
                    point: CGPoint(
                        x: pt.x,
                        // Play with this value to get the desired result
                        y: pt.y - CGFloat(valOffset) - valueFont.lineHeight), 
                    align: .Center,
                    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: valueFont, 
NSForegroundColorAttributeName: dataSet.valueTextColorAt(j)])
```

You have to add a number in the above code according to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this being suggested in some issues in the repo, but some properties and functions (`shouldDrawValues` and `_xBounds`) that are being used in the `drawValues` function are internal thus inaccessible if I override the `drawValues` method.

Comment: Also since you apply the custom `LineChartRenderer` to the LineChartView itself I don't see how could I customise the value label position so it's different for the different `dataSets`